# How to deploy ASP.NET Core MVC site to third party hosting service

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC, but an experienced ASP.NET developer. I have built my ASP.NET Core MVC site and run locally with Visual Studio.

Now I am trying to deploy to a third party hosting service. I created an account with IONOS. In Visual Studio, I setup my app to publish via FTP. I entered the IONOS ftp credentials, and did a publish through VS. It ran for a while, and then said it was successful. The log shows it publishing a bunch of folders, but not a `Bin` folder as I would expect.

I go to the IONOS site using FileZilla and poke around for my files.  I see some stuff in www folder (images, css, etc).  There is a folder that matches my project name, but I don't see anything in it. Since I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC, I really don't know what it should look like. Should there be a `web.config` for IIS? Where should the dlls be, and the executable be?

Since I am running on the development server, the website is hidden from me (I don't use IIS as I did for Asp.net).

IONOS is unable to help. They can't even tell me what web server is being used. I assume it is IIS. I put a test `index.htm` file in the root directory, and it does display when I hit my site. IONOS tells me I need to deploy my site using FileZilla for other.

I feel like I am missing a big something! Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get publish to work.  I am not sure what I changed to get rid of the HTTP 403.14 error but after deploying simple test projects I was able to get things working, somewhat.  I am still getting a HTTP 500 error but this is due to a database connection issue which I will post separately.

The issue with not deploying files was due to the setting "Allow publishing outside of visual studio..." not being checked.

A complicating factor is that IONOS support doesn't understand the deployment structure for an MVC Core site (and neither did I).  I was expecting to see html files, but instead I see dll's.  They kept telling me that I needed to copy files and that was not correct.

I hope this helps anyone else having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your .Net project, it will produce a folder named 'bin', go to it and find publish folder

path might be like this:

```
bin/Release/netX.0/publish
```

than upload all the files in publish to your FTP
But I don't know which folder you should upload to though.
In my host service I just upload to the project folder.

[image: create a new project]

[image: click publish]

Articles might help:

[Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I do not see a Publish folder under my Bin directory.  I did notice that by Bin folder was set to "Exclude from Project" so I assume that is why the files were not deployed.  This must be the default setting because I did not change it.  I right mouse clicked on Bin, and selected Publish.  It copied the files out there, but it still gets a HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error because there is no startup file.  I don't understand how to configure this.  Also, if I look under project properties, Output Type is set to Console App.  Is that correct?

Comment: No. You should start a new project again and choose Web application.

In solution mode, right click your project and select publish and find the publish folder inside bin.

I edited my answer, check the image.

Comment: The one I am using says: ASP.NET Core Web App (Model View Controller).  That is the one I selected when I created my project.  I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.5.0.  I create the project, and go to project properties, and it still says Console App.  I don't see any other applicable project type when creating a new project.  Mine is a web app.  It runs in the browser.

Comment: I made some progress...I created a new sample project using ASP.NET Core Web App template, compiled it, and deployed.  Was able to make work on my hosted site.  Then I tried creating another project using ASP.NET Core Web App (Model View  Controller) template.  I compiled, deployed, and it worked.  So I have determined that it is not the project type (template) that is the issue.  This also proves that either type can be hosted on IONOS.  But I am still having trouble getting my project to deploy.  When I publish, it is not copying any files.  My publish setup is exactly the same as test.

Comment: What is preventing my project from publishing?  BTW:  The project properties shows "Console App" for the working and non-working projects.  This is misleading but apparently irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that IONOS also support .net core on their platform. I believe that you can follow this blog https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-5-on-asphostportal-hosting/, the steps are almost same. I can publish .net core without any issue. If you have error, please advise here.